# Double For Loop and calculate averages in R

Tags: r, for-loop, mean

I have a minor problem, and I'm unsure how to fix the error.

Basically, I have two columns and I want to use a Double For Loop to calculate the averages between each number in both columns so it results in a vector of averages. To clarify, apply and mean functions isn't the best function because I need only half of the total possible combinations to obtain averages. For example:

```
Col1<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
Col2<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
Q1<-data.frame(cbind(Col1, Col2))

Q1$mean<-0
for (i in 1:length(Q1$Col1)) {
  for (j in i+1:length(Q1$Col2)) {
    Q1$mean[i]<-(Q1$Col1[i]+Q1$Col2[j])/2
  }
}
```

Basically, for each number in Q1$Col1, I want it average it with Q1$Col2. The reason why I want to use a double for loop is to eliminate duplicates. This is the matrix version to provide visualization:

```
1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0
1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5
2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0
2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5
3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5 5.0
```

Here, each row represents a number from Q1$Col1 and each column represents a number from Q1$Col2. However, notice that there is redundancy on both sides of the matrix diagonal. So using the Double For Loop, I eliminate the redundancy to obtain the averages of the unique combination of cases. Using the matrix above, it should look like this:

```
1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0
    2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5
        3.0 3.5 4.0
            4.0 4.5
                5.0
```

Comment: Your example is not reproducible because neither you have two columns in `Q1` or you can do such operations as `Q1$Col1` on a matrix. What is the desired output here?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I made the adjustments. Basically, for each number in Q1$Col1, I want it average it with Q1$Col2. The reason why I want to use a double for loop is to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: I am puzzled about what is the expected outcome of this algorithm, but probably it has a mistake: `i+1:length(Q1$Col2)` first produces a sequence from 1 to `length(Q1$Col2)` and then adds 1 to every element of the vector. Perhaps, OP meant a sequence from `i+1` to `length(Q1$Col2)`, which can be obtained by  `(i+1):length(Q1$Col2)`, for example.

Comment: @MaratTalipov I made the adjustments. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Not very much, to be honest. Could you show the manually calculated expected output for your data set?

Comment: In your second loop, try putting `i + 1` within parenthesis as in `(i+1)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, even in this case, the output will be identical to that produced by `with(Q1, Col1/2 + Col2[nrow(Q1)]/2)` which doesn't sound like what OP wants, so I guess the algorithm is wrong somewhere else as well.

Comment: @MaratTalipov Give me a second. I'm trying to code through a hangover.

Comment: @DavidArenburg False alarm. it didn't work. Let me produce the results manually first.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I made the edits. Hope it clarifies things.

Comment: So this triangle is your desired output or just the diagonal?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I want a vector that represents the values in the triangle.

Comment: The mean of each row?

Comment: The means of all the unique combinations between the two columns.

Comment: `rowMeans(expand.grid(Col1, Col2))`  perhaps?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Is there a way to obtain the values without the diagonal line?

Comment: How about `colMeans(combn(unique(c(Col1, Col2)), 2))`? Or just `combn(unique(c(Col1, Col2)), 2, mean)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg You sir are a savior! What do you want me to do? haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you're asking is this: given two vectors of numbers, how can I find the mean of the first items in each vector, the mean of the second items in each vector, and so on. If that's the case, then here is a way to do that.

First, you want use `cbind()` not `rbind()` in order to get columns not rows.

```
Col1<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
Col2<-c(2,3,4,5,6)
Q1<-cbind(Col1, Col2)
```

Then you can use the function `[rowMeans()][1]` to figure out (you guessed it) the means of each row. (See also `rowSums()` and `colMeans()` and `colSums()`.)

```
rowMeans(Q1)
#> [1] 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5
```

The more general way to do this is the `apply()` function, which will let us apply a function to each column or row. Here we use the argument `1` to apply it to rows (because the first row takes the first item from `Col1` and `Col2`, etc.).

```
apply(Q1, 1, mean)
```

The results are these:

```
#> [1] 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5
```

If you really want them in your existing matrix, you could do something like this:

```
means <- rowMeans(Q1)
cbind(Q1, means)
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the loops to get the averages, you can use vectorised operations:

```
Col1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
Col2 <- c(2,3,4,5,6)
Mean <- (Col1+Col2)/2
Q1 <- rbind(Col1, Col2, Mean)
```

However rbind treats your vectors as rows, you could use cbind for columns.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the `outer` function to first calculate the averages, then use `lower.tri`to fill the area underneath the diagonal of the matrix with `NA` values.

```
matrix<-outer(Q1$Col1, Q1$Col2, "+")/2
matrix[lower.tri(matrix)] = NA
```